# Is this login code vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-injection

```
String sSQL = "select RFC,Contraseña from Administradores where RFC='" + txtUsuario.getText() + "' and Contraseña='" + txtContrasena.getText() + "'";

String[] registros = new String[2];
Try  {
    conect();
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + base);
    Statement stat = conexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sSQL);
    while (rs.next()) {
        registros[0] = rs.getString("RFC");
        registros[1] = rs.getString("Contraseña");
    }
    stat.close();
    conexion.close();
} catch (SQLException ex)    
{    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DB connection error");    
}
if ((txtContrasena.getText().equals(registros[1])) || (txtUsuario.getText().equals(registros[0]))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Granted");
    Escoger variable = new Escoger();
    variable.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
} else {
    if (txtContrasena.getText() != (registros[1])) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: If you're not using prepared statements, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

This...

```
String sSQL = "select RFC,Contraseña from Administradores where RFC='" + 
              txtUsuario.getText() + "' and Contraseña='" + 
              txtContrasena.getText() + "'";
```

Would automatically suggest it is.  Anything that is input into the `txtUsuario` and `txtContrasena` could contain valid SQL code that could be executed by the SQL engine of the database.

You should be using:

```
String sSQL = "select RFC,Contraseña from Administradores where RFC=? and Contraseña=?";
```

You will then need to change...

```
Statement stat = conexion.createStatement();
```

To

```
PreparedStatement stat = conexion.preapreStatement(sSQL);
stat.bindString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
stat.bindString(2, txtContrasena.getText());
```

Take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Further, you should never store a password in the database. You should store a hashed version of the password in the database, and to check the password you hash what you're given (securely, https if via web) and compare that hash value with the hash value in the database. Use a secure hash algorithm (not MD5, for example). Better yet, concatenate the username and password and hash that, then use that as the value to store in the database and compare (that way two users with the same password don't hash to the same value).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use PreparedStatements instead. Replace the user and password values with placeholders.

```
String SampleQuery = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE User = ? AND Password = ?";
String UserName = UsernameBox.getText();
String Password = PasswordBox.getText();

PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(SampleQuery);
prep.setString(1, UserName);
prep.setString(2, Password);
ResultSet result = prep.executeQuery();
```